# About the python for loop

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows, for-loop, iterator

Inside the for Loop there, when I (for loop index) reaches index 4 it executes the codes from line 11 to 13 and also decrements the index variable by one unit. So the value of I is 3 now and when for loop is at its next iteration the value of I should be 4 but it assigns 5 to the I.

```
l = [3,5,2,4]
l.append(7)
print(l)
l.extend([6,8,9,11,13])
print(l)
for i in range(0,len(l),1):
    if len(l)<i:
         break
    if l[i]>=7:
        del(l[i])
        i=i-1
print(l)
```

Python Tutor:
[image]

Comment: Subtracting 1 from `i` doesn't make it one less the next time through the `for` loop. It will be assigned the next value from the `range` function regardless of how you modify the value of `i` in the loop.

Comment: Please format your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For your use case, it may be better to use a while loop which would allow you to change the value of the index variable. Perhaps the following would suffice for your case:

```
l = [3,5,2,4]
l.append(7)
print(l)
l.extend([6,8,9,11,13])
print(l)
i = 0
while i in range(0,len(l)):
    if l[i]>=7:
        del(l[i])
        i=i-1
    i+=1
print(l)
```